# What is the shortcut to use Zen Coding for Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, shortcut, emmet

What is the shortcut key (Tab?) to activate Zen Coding within Notepad++ once Zen is installed?  Could it be F1?  Tab is not working.  Nothing in Preferences under Editing.

Answer (score 8):

Go to settings > Shortcut Mapper > Plugin Commands tab.

Look for "Expand Abbreviations" it has the shortcut "Alt-Ctrl-Enter" by default. 
Double-click that line (or hit Modify button) and deselect all checkboxes. Select "Tab" from the drop-down list of available key commands, and boom! Tab now Expands Abbreviations when it finds them, and otherwise functions as the normal Tab.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

You have set a shortcut yourself.
Go to settings > Shortcut Mapper > Plugin Commands tab.
There at the end you will find Zen coding commands. Find command named "Expand Abbreviation" and Double click on empty column next to it and define new shortcut key. You may need to restart notepad++ app. Verify this change by going to "plugin > Zen coding" and the shortcut key will appear with command name.
Don't give an already occupied shortcut. Try with some hard key combination. like for me its "ctrl + alt + enter"

Answer (score 4):

The Default Shortcut Key to "Expand Abbreviation" in Notepadd++ is Ctrl+E, is you can see it under "Zen Coding" menu item; You can change shortcuts for Zencodeing in "\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\NppScripting\includesfiles\Zen Coding.js". At the very bottom of this file, you can find and edit keyboard shortcuts. But if you use \t for this action, it won't work for indentation, so it's not recommended.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue after installing zen last week. I came here and it gave me the gist of how to fix it, but what I noticed is that my *default* setting to expand was ctrl+alt+enter. This is also the default to add a return before, so the reason it didn't work is because the return before command was overriding. By changing the default expand function to a free combination (I use ctrl+alt+E) it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so for those of you who've come here with the same problem:
1) Make sure you've read the readme file and you've put the install files in the correct place (check again).
2) Save your document as HTML or CSS (only then will it trigger the shortcuts).
3) Check out the cheat sheet online, type one of the relevant shortcuts, and then hit (Ctrl+E).

If that doesn't work you've done something wrong.