# How to include Zen Coding in Notepad ++?

Tags: notepad++, emmet

I include downloaded zen file to Notepad++ plugin folder and restart the program. But When I press Ctrl+E to expand a code it does not work? Anyone please help. I'm new in this track.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the shortcut to use Zen Coding for Notepad++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528840/what-is-the-shortcut-to-use-zen-coding-for-notepad)